# Update TextView from AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to use the AlertDialog in android, specifically I want the user to input some information in an EditText field, then once finished to press OK and for the TextView to be updated to the inputted value.

Everything worked well up until I wanted to update the TextView when the user clicks OK. Now the app keeps crashing when the user clicks OK.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.simple.plain.calendar;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String input = "";
    EditText edit;
    TextView text;


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //Declaring the textview and button.
       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_tv);
       Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.surprise);

       //When button is clicked, do the following.
       but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
              showDialog();
           }
       });
    }


private void showDialog(){
    // Create the Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null));

    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_text);

    // Add OK button
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User clicked OK button
            input = edit.getText().toString();
            text.setText(input);
        }
    });


    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });

// Set other dialog properties
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);



// Create the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getGroupId()){

            case R.id.action_settings:
                    return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

**dialog_signin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/username" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="@string/password"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#e0e2e5">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >


    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/calendar_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="FireMissilesDialogFragment"
        android:text="@string/surprise_me"
        android:id="@+id/surprise"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/new_text"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How does it crash? What exception is thrown, where?

Comment: @Lucurious it says, 'unfortunately Calendar has stopped' when the user clicks the ok button in the dialog.

Comment: That's what I figured, but what does the IDE show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EditText is null, because you are trying to find it by id from the Activity's layout, while it is actually in the dialog's view.

Replace these two lines:

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null));

edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
```

With those:

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
builder.setView(dialogView );

edit = (EditText) dialogView .findViewById(R.id.username);
```